# How to configure Android Studio not generate deprecate code?

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated

I have installed latest Android Studio (version 1.2 build on 29 April 2015) and created a new project from it.

I can see it generates code that uses deprecated classes like ActionBarActivity and etc. These classes were deprecated several years ago.

Is there a way to configure it to generate decent code that is not deprecated?

Comment: Several years?  What a joke.  `ActionBarActivity` was deprecated in support library 22.1.1 aka the latest version,  and you just have to replace it with `AppCompatActivity` which codewise does the exact same thing.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, what about addPreferencesFromResource? You had to jump the gun just like that?

Comment: that's because `PreferenceFragment` doesn't exist under API Level 11, although you **can** hack it in using something like this https://gist.github.com/cbeyls/7475726 . `addPreferencesFromResource` works perfectly fine on all Android versions despite being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this app theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` always. it will generate new code.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```